# Community user's profile is not browsable anymore?

Tags: support, status-completed, community-user

https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/

I can't browse community user's profile. It says Page Not Found.

Is it only me? or just a temporary issue?

Comment: Same for me. I can't see it anymore.

Comment: that link says page not found to me too, but I've no idea what it should be

Comment: @Lo'oris - it used to show you a brief description of the role of the community user.

Comment: "Page Not Found" for Moderators too. May be restricted to Developer-team access only.

Comment: This will be pushed tonight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug in some changes I did to our main routing code.  A fix will be pushed in tonight's deployment.

Don't worry, we'll also have some better unit tests around these routes using the awesome [MvcContrib TestHelper](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TestHelper&referringTitle=Documentation#Routes) assembly :)

Comment: Thank you for letting us know its a temporary issue. :-)

Comment: @S.Mark no problem - I screwed up and the community must know my shame.

Comment: Perhaps on stackoverflow.com/users/${num} pages the error page should say "User not found"

Comment: `if (userId > 0) { //display page } else { //error }` ? :-]

Comment: @Brad, I think they reuse that Page Not Found 404 error page on lot of place. so, IMHO, making special error page on user page could be extra effort for dev team? or may be I am wrong.

Comment: @Gnoupi - haha, close... it was a route constraint regex that didn't account for leading `-` for negative numbers!

Comment: @Jarrod, +1, if only we could vote on users directly... I suppose a +1 on your comment is just as good.

Comment: Confirmed that its now works on rev 2010.5.11.3, thanks

Comment: Can we know which is the current revision?

Comment: @stacker - bottom right, under the "peak" logo.